# Reuse Java Bean in Jackson Library

Tags: java, jackson

When using the Jackson library from FasterXML using an `ObjectMapper` a new instance of an object (Java Bean) is instantiated every time a JSON string is read. In the following example, a new instance of class `Person` is created:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
Person p = om.readValue("{\"name\":\"Bob\",\"age\":20}", Person.class);
```

How can I reuse an old instance of `Person` and avoiding creating new instances? In this way I avoid doing unnecessary garbage collection.

Comment: Uhm, why? Object creation is cheap, unlike common folklore would have you believe

Comment: Are you trying to outperform the garbage collector?

Comment: No reason to reuse `Person` instances, but you might want to consider reusing the same `ObjectMapper` instance.

Comment: I know that for most cases object creation is cheap. But I am running Hadoop on large amounts of data and reusing objects in this context really improves performance. It's tested ;-)